# Why doesn't Bootstrap popover scroll to form element?

Tags: html, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, validation, popover

I have resorted to using Bootstrap popover because HTML validation exhibits the same behavior I am now experiencing. Perhaps the solution for one will work for both.

JS

```
var validate = validate || {};
validate.issueError = function ($elem, msg, placement) {
    placement = placement == undefined ? 'bottom' : placement;
    $elem.attr('data-toggle', 'popover');
    $elem.attr("data-offset", "0 25%");
    var exclamationPoint = "<span style='font-weight: bold; font-size:medium; color: white; background-color: orange; height: 12px; padding: 1px 6px; margin-right: 8px;'>!</span>";
    var content = "<span style='font-size: smaller;'>" + msg + "</span>";
    $elem.popover("destroy").popover({
        html: true,
        placement: placement,
        content: exclamationPoint + content
    })
    $elem.focus();
    $elem.popover('show');
    setTimeout(function () { $elem.popover('hide') }, 5000);
    $elem.on("keydown click", function () {
        $(this).popover('hide');
        $(this).off("keydown click")
    })
}
validate.edits = {
    required: function ($form) {
       var $reqFlds = $form.contents().find('[required], [data-required]');
        $reqFlds.each(function () {
            var $this = $(this);
            var result = ($this.filter("input, select, textarea").length) ? $this.val() : $this.text();
        if (!$.trim(result)) {
            validate.issueError($this, "Please fill out this field.");
            return false;
        }
    });
    return true;
}
```

HTML (note I have substituted "required' with "data-required" to force the Bootstrap routines).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Writer's Tryst - Writers Form</title>
        <link type="text/css" href="css/writers.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <style>
            body {padding: 0 20px;}
            .limited-offer {
                background-color: white;
                padding:  3px;
                margin-bottom: 12px;
                border-radius: 4px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <img id="img-writers" src="#" alt="images" />
            <form id="form-writers" method="post" class="form-horizontal well">
                <h1>Writers</h1>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="title" class="col-lg-3 control-label">Title</label>
                    <div class="col-lg-9">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" data-required id="title" name="title" autofocus="true" placeholder="Title" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="form-type" class="col-lg-3 control-label">Type of work</label>
                    <div class="col-lg-9">
                        <select class="form-control" data-required id="form-type" name="form-type"></select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="genre" class="control-label col-lg-3">Genre</label>
                    <div class="col-lg-9">
                        <select id="genre" name="genre" class="form-control" data-required></select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="nbr-pages" class="control-label col-lg-3">Number Pages</label>
                    <div class="col-lg-9">
                        <input type="number" id="nbr-pages" name="nbr-pages" class="form-control" data-required placeholder="Pages" />
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div id="tips">The objective of a synopsis or query letter is to entice enablers into requesting your manuscript. 
                                It must be concise and to the point and of course very well written. One page is preferred and no more than 3 pages will be accepted.
                                <a href="uploads/ron/3997524697.pdf" target="_blank">Sample Query Letter</a>                        
                </div>
                <p id="file-warning" class="thumbnail">Your synopsis/query letter must be a PDF file.
                    <a target="_blank" href="https://www.freepdfconvert.com/" target="_blank">Free file conversion to PDF.</a>
                </p>
                <div>
                    <a id="file-upload" class="btn btn-custom-primary btn-file btn-block text-xs-center" role="button">Choose PDF to Upload
                        <br/><div id="filename" class="btn-block" style="color: #fff">No file chosen</div>
                    </a>
                    <input type="file" id="file2upload" style="display: none">
                </div><br/>
                <div class="form-group">
<!--            <button type="submit" id="writers-submit" class="btn btn-custom-success btn-block m-t-8">Submit</button>-->
                </div>
                <div class="limited-offer">For a limited time, writer submissions will cost <span style="color: #f00; font-weight:bold">$15.00</span> to offset screening and editing costs and to promote quality synopsises and query letters. We reserve the right to change this policy without notice.</div>

<!--                <form id="form-paypal" name="form-paypal" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top" onsubmit="return ajaxSubmit()">-->
                <form id="form-paypal" name="form-paypal" method="post" target="_top">
                    <input type="submit" class="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
                    <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="U2LE82Z45PJ54">
                    <input style="display: block; margin: 0 auto;" id="but-pp" type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_paynowCC_LG.gif" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
                    <img alt="PayPal" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
                </form>
                <input id="userid" name="userid" type="hidden" />
                <input id="filesize-limit" name="filesize-limit" type="hidden" value="150000" /> 
            </form>
        </div>
        <script>
            angular.element(document).ready(function () {
                showImages($("#form-writers"), $("#img-writers"), "authors", ["blake.jpg", "Melville.jpg", "lewis-carroll.jpg", "stephen-king.jpg", "twain.jpg", "camus.jpg", "nietzsche.jpg", "hesse.jpg"]);
            });
            $(function () {
                populateWritersDropdowns();
                $(document).on('change', ':file', function () {
                    var input = $(this),
                    numFiles = input.get(0).files ? input.get(0).files.length : 1,
                    label = input.val().replace(/\\/g, '/').replace(/.*\//, '');
                    input.trigger('fileselect', [numFiles, label]);
                });
                $('#file-upload').on('click', function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $('#file2upload')[0].click();
                });
                $("#file2upload").on("change", function () {
                    var filepath = $('#file2upload')[0].value;
                    var filename = filepath.substr(filepath.lastIndexOf("\\") + 1);
                    $("#filename").text(filename)
                });
                $("#but-pp").on("mousedown", function (e) {
                    //if (!$("#form-writers").get(0).checkValidity()) return false;
                    var $ret = validate.edits.required($("#form-writers"));
                    alert($ret.length);
                    if ($ret != true) {
                        $ret.focus();
                        return false;
                    }
                    if (!validate.edits.requireFile($("#filename"))) return false;
                    if (!fileEdits()) return false;
               
                    ajaxSubmit();
                    function fileEdits() {
                        var fileSizeLimit = $("#filesize-limit").val();
                        var file = document.getElementById('file2upload').files[0];
                        var fileName = file.name;
                        var fileExt = fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
                        var fileSize = file.size;
                        if (fileSize > fileSizeLimit) {
                            showMessage(0, "Your file-size (" + (Math.round(parseInt(fileSize) / 1000)).toLocaleString() + "kb) exceeds the limit of " + (fileSizeLimit.toLocaleString() / 1000) + "kb");
                            return false;
                        } else {
                            if (fileExt.toLowerCase() != "pdf") {
                                showMessage(0, "Your synopsis / query letter MUST be a PDF file.");
                                return false;
                            };
                            return true;
                        }
                    };
                    function ajaxSubmit() {
                        var file_data = $('#file2upload').prop('files')[0];
                        var form_data = new FormData();
                        form_data.append('file', file_data);
                        form_data.append('action', "upload");
                        form_data.append('title', $("#title").val());
                        form_data.append('form-type', $("#form-type").val());
                        form_data.append('genre', $("#genre").val());
                        form_data.append('nbr-pages', $("#nbr-pages").val());
                        form_data.append('account-id', localStorage.getItem("account-id"));
                        ajax('post', 'php/writers.php', form_data, success, 'Error uploading file:', 'text', false, false, false);
                        function success(result) {
                            if (result.indexOf("PDF") == -1) {
                                showMessage(1, "Your submission will go live and you will be notified after our reviews are complete.");
                                var data = {};
                                data['writer-id'] = result;
                                ajax('post', 'php/paypal-ipn.php', data, listenerStarted);
                                function listenerStarted(result) {
                                    alert("pp=" + result);
                                }
                            } else {
                                showMessage(0, result);
                            }
                            setTimeout(function () {
                                document.getElementById('form-writers').reset();
                                $("#filename").text("No file chosen");
                            }, 5000);
                        };
                    };
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```